# Using audio services on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtual-machines, drivers, audio

Software that I modified for use in a particular game takes player input, feeds it to a text-to-speech engine, and outputs a `.wav` audio file, which the game then runs, making the player's character "talk."

When run on a desktop, the program works perfectly. When run on the server, it only works while Remote Desktop Connection is actively connected. From what research I've done, it seems that this is the case because remote audio is only active while connected to RDC. I'm not fully sure, but what I do know is that when not connected to the server, the program used to generate the audio file crashes because "No Wave Output Device is Present"."

What can I do to ensure that this program is still able to generate `.wav` files even when not connected through RDC? In an attempt to solve, I installed WinAmp and Virtual Audio Cable, but I have no clue how I would use either of them. Information on this kind of topic is startlingly lacking on the internet.

For reference, here is a link to the software that I modified for use within the game: https://github.com/whatsecretproject/SharpTalk

Comment: Does your server have an audio device?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the "Desktop Experience" feature? (Server Manager > Select "Features" in the tree and then Add Features in the context menu)

Comment: I have. As far as I know, it did nothing besides allow me to install Windows Media Player. What actually got the program to work on the server when RDP'd was navigating to tsconfig.msc, looking at RDP-tcp properties, and unchecking "Disable Audio". But that only works for when I'm remotely connected to the server, which is obviously an unacceptable solution.